# See background color only through circle center

Tags: jquery, css

I have a yellow background and a circle with no background color but with a grey border. How would I go if I wanted everything outside that circle to be white, everything except the inside of the circle where you could see the yellow background from the div below it?

I don't need a workaround to replace the css circle with an image. I need to figure out a CSS and if needed JS soulution.

**HTML**

```
<div id="background">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#background{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ffff99;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}
#background:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:2px solid #999;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/n3c1t0ee/) to test on.

Expected output :
[image]

### Getting closer

> ..using a radial gradient. The only thing left now is to keep the
>   circle shape while the div height and width are 100%.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/n3c1t0ee/2/)

### Update 2

> This IS what I want to achieve but not how I imagined I would achieve
>   it...is there a better way of obtaining [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/n3c1t0ee/4/)?

Comment: Why not just change the `background-color` values? Do you have a image/screenshot of the expected output?

Comment: @ManojKumar Updated with a representative image of the expected output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a hack here.. Just added a **huge** border to the circle.. Then positioned it inside the `#background` div..

Here is the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/n3c1t0ee/6/

```css
#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffff99;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#background:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1000px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
  position: relative;
  left: -900px;
  top: -900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that I will have trouble centering the circle :-?

Comment: Well, I fixed my issue using your method with some work so I guess I'm gonna mark your answer as the right one :) Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating parent element for `.circle` , utilizing `z-Index` , setting `.circle` `background` to `transparent !important`

```
`background:transparent;`
```

```css
#background{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    z-Index:0;
}
#background:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    left:40%;
    top:100px;
    position:absolute;
    z-Index:10;
    background:#fff !important;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.circle{
    top:-2px;
    left:-2px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:2px solid #999;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
    background:transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
    <div class="wrap">
        abc
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n3c1t0ee/3/

Comment: Hello! Well, it already is, being undefined it's kinda transparent to begin with...the thing I want is everything around it to be white, except for that circle so I can see through it the #background div color.

Comment: Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/n3c1t0ee/2/ but to maintain the circle's shape.

Comment: This doesn't work..you just have 2 divs the same width and height one under the other...it's the same as adding a background color to the initial circle. I need to see the yellow color from the #background div and keep it 100% width and height. See the jsfiddle in the update of my answer. I only need to maintain the circle shape now...and I can't figure out how.

Comment: @Alin _"This doesn't work..you just have 2 divs the same width and height one under the other...it's the same as adding a background color to the initial circle. I need to see the yellow color from the #background div"_ ? What yellow color from `#background` `div` ? At image at Question , `#background` `div` background set to black ?

Comment: That is just a photoshop simulation showing the pixels from behind. Here, the yellow from here : http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/n3c1t0ee/2/  But when the window is not square, the circle keeps altering it's shape and i need it to remain a circle but i also need the <div id="background"...to be 100% width and height..

Comment: This IS what I want to achieve but not how I imagined I would achieve it...is there a better way of obtaining this? http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/n3c1t0ee/4/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, I used a transparant `radial-gradient` to make the hole and used `pointer-events: none` to make sure you can select the stuff beneath the layer. Then I aligned the text in the middle of the div. Check it out:

```css
.background {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}
.circle {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 100px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100px);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 100px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100px);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(transparent 100px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(transparent 100px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100px);
  pointer-events: none;
  display: table;
}
.circle p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="circle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just copied my code and added a square background! How does this meet my requirements? I said '**while** the height and width are 100%.' I need the #background 100% width and height. not a square and like I said, you didn't "come up with it" you just copied and changed a background size and color...:|

Comment: Well excuse me sir, but I didn't even see your Update 2 fiddle while I was writing the code

Comment: The same thing is in the first update too :)) sorrybut if you were in my place, wouldn've you have thought the same thing? :)) have a nice day and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added a white shadow to the circle

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px white;
```

```css
#background{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ffff99;
    white-space: nowrap;
 text-align:center;
}
#background:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:2px solid #999;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
</div>
```